# Can't get return values from methods ( java)

Tags: java, variables, methods, assign

Hey I don't understand **why, when this runs the calculation is equal to zero**. I've already assigned values to the variables in the main method. What is it I'm missing because I'm breaking my head trying to figure it out. Also I'm following from a really simple example I saw online that worked I just edited it to my needs. I'm relatively new so bear with me, it's my second month and I want to keep doing this.

```
public void myAtkStat(int myAtk) {
    System.out.println("Atk:" + myAtk);
    int meAtk = myAtk;
}

public int getmyAtk() {
    return meAtk;
}

public void defStat(int def) {
    System.out.println("Def :" + def);
    int defense = def;
}

public int getDefense() {
    return defense;
}

public void doCalculation() {
    System.out.println((getmyAtk() * 2) - getDefense());
}
```

Comment: You really need to go back to your book and learn about variable scoping . Your code makes very little sense. This shouldn't even compile. Your `getDefense` method doesn't contain a variable called `defense`, so you can't return it.

Comment: To elaborate, variables with the same name are *not* shared between methods. Make `defense` a member of a class to share it around.

Comment: I forgot to add that the variable int defense and atk are already declared in the class so my apologies for not being completely clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But in `defStat` you're redecorating `defense`, which shadows the class member with the same name.

Comment: *redeclare. See my answer for an elaboration.

Comment: I made it work already , I changed the code in both methods , Instead of writing int defense = def . I used  **this** 

this.defense =def;

I did the same thing in both of the methods and it worked just fine.

Comment: You should provide the `class` where these methods lie.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the attack value you're using a method variable. So you never set the value. You have to write this like as following :

```
public void myAtkStat (int myAtk) {
    System.out.println("Atk:" + myAtk);
    this.meAtk=myAtk;
}
```

You have the same problem for the variable defense (as they said in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
int defense = def;
```

Because you included a type (`int`), you created a new local variable. When you then assign to it, you're assigning to the new local variable, not the class member.

Include a type to create a new variable. Remove it in this case to refer to the class member.

Or, better yet, be explicit about which variable you want:

```
this.defense = def;
```